# Installing a "Shortcut" in the Application Menu from Python .desktop File

Tags: icons, .desktop, appmenu

I would like to install a chess GUI called "PyChess". Since the repo of my distribution (20.04) doesn't offer PyChes, I downloaded a .tar.gz file, extracted it, and with a simple `./pychess` (a python file in the program's folder starting the program) I can start the GUI.
The trouble is, that I would like to have my application visible in the menu (when I press super+A).

I have tried moving the `pychess.desktop` file into `/usr/share/applications` and the corresponding icon into `/usr/share/icons`, but to no avail: the application appears, but clicking it does nothing.

The content of the `pychess.desktop` file is as follows:

```
Type=Application
Name=PyChess
Comment=PyChess is a fully featured, nice looking, easy to use chess client for the Gnome desktop
GenericName=Chess Game
Icon=pychess
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=/home/carl/PyChess-1.0.3/pychess
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;BoardGame;
MimeType=application/x-chess-pgn;application/x-chess-epd;application/x-chess-fen;application/x-chess-pychess;
```

As you can see, I have tried using an absolute path under `Exec=`, where it has once been `Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= pychess`.

Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: pychess *is* in the repos. `sudo apt install pychess` <- works here, on 20.04. Its icon is in the menu after install.

Comment: I just checked, and you're absolutely right! However, it's using the version 0.12.2-1build1 which I assume is quite antique (the newest version is 1.0.3, as far as I know). But for last resort, yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is "env". The desktop recognizes that as a valid command, and because the `.desktop` file is correct otherwise, will show the icon in the launcher.

All that your command does, however, is setting an environment variable.

It sets the variable `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY`

to: `/home/carl/PyChess-1.0.3/pychess`.

That may not be what you thought the command you supplied did.

Test your command first on the terminal. If it works there, it is likely (but not guaranteed) to work also from the `.desktop` launcher.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The command (now modified: `Exec= env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= opt/PyChess.../pychess`) works flawlessly in the terminal. It doesn't in the app menu. I have checked the .desktop file and there don't seem to be any mistakes. :/

Comment: Perhaps first remove the space before "env".

Comment: Good point, but no change. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll look further for answers!

Comment: a simple restart did the job. Thank you for your time.